# Fine grained vs coarse grained domain model In Memory Data Grid

Tags: java, model, domain-driven-design, hazelcast, key-value-store

I am wondering which approach is better. Should we use fine grained entities on the grid and later construct functionaly rich domain objects out of the fined grained entities.

Or alternatively we should construct the course grained domain objects and store them directly on the grid and the entities we just use for persistence.

Edit: I think that this question is not yet answered completely. So far we have comments from Hazelcast,Gemfire and Ignite. We are missing Infinispan, Coherence .... That is for completion sake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Valentin, it mainly depends on the system you want to use. Normally I would consider to store enhanced domain objects directly, anyhow if you would just have very few objects but their size is massive you end up with bad distribution and unequal memory usage on the nodes. If your domain object are "normally" sized and you have plenty, you shouldn't worry.

In Hazelcast it is better to store those objects directly but be aware of using a good serialization system as Java Serialization is slow. If you want to query on properties inside your domain objects you should also consider adding indexes.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer. Why on Hazelcast Enhanced objects is better ? What is different about Hazelcast ?

Comment: Hazelcast doesn't offer join operations, therefore you would have to do multiple requests to retrieve all your objects or, alternatively, add data affinity and EntryProcessors to generate your domain object on-the-fly (node local) which is kind of the same idea as the join operation. Anyhow Hazelcast is all about speed and re-generating the same objects just doesn't sound right :) I would recommend to read about denormalization if you don't know this term (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). I hope that makes sense, otherwise feel free to ask further questions :)

Comment: You are giving a lot of information and I am having a bit difficulties digesting it all. I am a bit unsure if you are recommending storing fine grained objects and then use the EntityProcessor to generate the enhanced ones. This is an alternative if we can not store directly the enhanced right ?

Comment: Ok I think I am starting to understand what you are saying. You are saying that your first choice is to store the enhanced objects directly. Your second choice if this is not possible is to use data afinity + Entry Processors. There is only one thing I am not completely sure. Once you process the map with EntyProcessor to create a rich object, do you persist it or just consume it in order to complete the task? I personaly don't see value in persisting it once more. Isn't this just waste of memory ?

Comment: EntryProcessor doesn't store the enriched objects, it'll just return it based on your "query", therefore they'll be regenerated everytime. And yes, storing enriched objects directly is the preferred way.

Comment: I tryed to use te Data Afinity on a two node setup on my wifi network which has significant latency -5-8ms as you pointed out. I configured a classical Customer - Order one to many relationship. Kept both entries in separate maps and set an index on customerId in Order. I did not find any way to access directly the colocated entries of the Order by customerId. SO I used Predicate to fetch them. Due to the network latency the performance was TERRIBLE. Why is it so difficult to just fetch the entries that are co located ?

Comment: Why is there network activity at all. Is it because of the index ? It is a very simple situation. I want to process all Orders on all Customers and I have all customer Ids. How can I access the customer directly without Hazelcast trigering remote calls ?

Comment: Depending on how you submit the predicate you always get network activity (as the predicate is sent to all members even though only one will have a result). Predicates itself cannot query co-located entries as those are meant to be pure queries (in relational terms think of it as the where-clause). If you want to access further data you need an EntryProcessor or the distributed ExecutorService. Maybe it is easier to make a small github project and I can help you. Apart from that, Hazelcast is a key-value store and highly optimized for key-based access but I bet we can speed it up :)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your willingness to support me. Here I have setup a small project https://github.com/alpet/hazelcastcolocation  It uses executor service to submit tasks to each node. Each node must traverse all of the customers and process all of the orders. This is why I fetch the localKeyset for Customers. The problem now is how to navigate from the Customer to the Order when I don't know the orderId. Do I need to fetch all the orderIds in advance as well and make a join. Is this the solution ? Isn't there an easier way to navigate from the Customer to the Order.

Comment: I'll have a look at the execution runtime but I suspect that there's a deserialization involved for an, yet, unknown reason. If every order would have to be deserialized, it explains why the query is so horribly slow. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Your example defines the index but the config object is not passed to the Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance call and therefore never used :) I'll send a PR to your repo to also show how to speed up serialization using DataSerializable

Comment: Hello, i wrote the example in a hury. In my real project it is defined correctly and the entity is deserialized only 1 time. The problem is my slow network, when I preloaded all the local keys for the order region and stored them in a TreeMap in order to have a fast lookup and 0 network calls the speed improved drasticaly.

Comment: I will add the second example tomorrow morning. The problem is that with a slow network, Even if it hit the index. IT is still too slow in my opinion. If the latency is in the 5ms reach and you have to process thousands og records it becoms a lot.

Comment: There should be a way to navigate between colocated entities without network overhead. Maling this treemap is like doing a join, so that i precalculate all the keys in advance. But isnt there a better way?

Comment: There are no relations between different data structures. I'm pretty sure it is still possible to speed it up and there should be no network interaction if all keys are colocated. I don't even think there is one either.

Comment: Hello Noctarius, first it is working! Second to be honest I feel a little bit stupid. I can swear that I tested the localKeyset(Predicate) on wednesday, but aparantly I might have missed an index as you said above. Because today it is working :D Thanks a lot for the support. I noticed that you have changed from Runnable to Callable<Void> is there any particular difference ?`I was left with the impression that Runnable stands for a job that does not return results.  And thanks again for the support.

Comment: I just changed it for the reason I had a better runtime value when starting multiple nodes (do to waiting for the futures to return :-))

Answer (score 2):

I believe it can differ from one Data Grid to another. I'm more familiar with Apache Ignite, and in this case fine grained approach works much better, because it's more flexible and in many cases gives better data distribution and therefore better scalability. Ignite also provides rich SQL capabilities [1] that allow to join different entities and execute indexed search. This way you will not lose performance with fine grained model.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

Comment: What about co-location ? When you have complex objects that you persist on the grid you know for sure that the data is co-located, but if you work with fine grained objects how do you know that the nested agregations are located on the same machine ?

Comment: This is right, you have to properly collocate data when using joins. Here is how this should be done in Ignite: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation

Comment: Also note that starting with 1.6, Ignite will allow to execute joins without collocation. But this is not free, of course, and will affect performance in a bad way. So collocated approach is still recommended.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of a coarse-grained object is data consistency.  Everything in that object gets saved atomically.  But if you split that object up into 4 small objects, you run the risk that 3 objects save and 1 fails (for whatever reason).

We use GemFire, and tend to favor coarse-grained objects...up to a point.  For example our Customer object contains a list of Addresses.  An alternative design would be to create one GemFire region for "Customer" and a separate GemFire region for "CustomerAddresses" and then hope you can keep those regions in sync.

The downside is that every time someone updates an Address, we re-write the entire Customer object.  That's not very efficient, but our traffic patterns show that address changes are very rare (compared to all the other activity), so this works out fine.

One experience we've had though is the downside of using Java Serialization for long-term data storage.  We avoid it now, because of all the problems caused by object compatibility as objects change over time.  Not to mention it becomes headache for .NET clients to read the objects.  :)